# How to identify timezone by string time and convert multiple timezones to one timezone in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datetime, timezone, datetime-conversion

I have list of records with dateTime in different timezones

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dateTime": "2023-01-01T14:10:24.478Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "dateTime": "2023-01-22T08:39:48.374+08:00"
    }.
    {
        "id": 3,
        "dateTime": "2023-01-22T08:39:48.374+05:30"
    }
]

data class Record(val id: Int, val dateTime: String)
```

I need to convert these all dateTime to my timezone (Eg: +04:00)

Is there a best way to identify timezone by dateTime value to convert it to my timezone? or do we need substring dateTime and find timezone value add custom method to get timezone?

Eg:

```
fun String.timezone() : String? {
    return when(this) {
        "+05:30" -> "Asia/Calcutta"
        "Z" -> "UTC"
            .....
        else -> null
    }
}
```

*(I know how to convert dateTime to my tomezone if know tomezone of dateTime)*

Comment: None of these strings indicate a time zone. They're offsets, and there can be multiple different time zones in the same offset at the same instant. However, the values *do* identify a point in time, so if you actually *have* your time zone, you can easily convert the value to that time zone. You should be parsing these strings as `OffsetDateTime` values, as that's what they represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how to map an offset to a time zone? You cannot. At any moment, several time zones can coincidentally share the same offset.

You said:

> my timezone (Eg: +04:00)

Correction… Your example `+04:00` is an offset from UTC, *not* a time zone.

An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC. In Java, use [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) with `OffsetDateTime`.

A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians. In Java, use [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) with `ZonedDateTime`.

|  |  | Point on timeline |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Offset from UTC | `ZoneOffset` | `OffsetDateTime` |
| Time zone | `ZoneId` | `ZonedDateTime` |

A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`. For example, `Africa/Casablanca` or `Pacific/Auckland`. FYI, the time zone `Asia/Calcutta` has been renamed `Asia/Kolkata`.

Parse your inputs as `OffsetDateTime` objects.

(Java syntax; I don’t know Kotlin)

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2023-01-22T08:39:48.374+08:00" ) ;
```

Apply your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Dubai" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```